# Count symbols Char's in String Python

Tags: python, string

I'd like to count repetead chars in string, I know about count() function, but it doesn't helps me in my current task.  For example , the **String Sample Input is**
: `s = 'aaaabbсaa'`
**Sample Output should be :**`a4b2с1a2`
I will appreciate for any suggestions, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with `itertools.groupby`:

```
s = 'aaaabbсaa'

from itertools import groupby

result=''.join(f'{label}{len(list(group))}' for label, group in groupby(s))
#same as: 
#result = [f'{label}{len(list(group))}' for label, group in groupby(s)]
#result=''.join(result)
```

Output:

```
result
'a4b2с1a2'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this as well:

```
s = 'aaaabbсaa'
new_s=''
num=0
prev=s[0]
for i in range(len(s)):
    if(s[i]==prev):
       num += 1
    else:
       new_s+=s[i-1]
       new_s+=str(num)
       prev=s[i]
       num=1
    if(i==len(s)-1)
       new_s+=s[i]
       new_s+=str(num)

print(new_s)
```

Output:

'a4b2c1a2'